# Maven Compilation - Facebook missing symbol

Tags: android, facebook, maven

I am trying to use the maven command in the terminal

```
mvn clean install
```

but for some reason, today the terminal wants to throw some errors.
These errors all revolve around Facebook as well.

```
...src/com/facebook/Settings.java:[26,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable BuildConfig
[ERROR] location: package com.facebook.android
```

How would I go about ridding myself of these errors, I have been searching all day for possibilites with no luck. Not sure where to go from here, any advice would be appreciated.

Is there something I can tweak in the Pom.xml?

Comment: Can you publish code from Settings.java?

Comment: After a couple hours of pulling my hair out, I figured out the problem. I forgot to add on the question that I was signing the APK during this mvn clean install -P release. My keystore path was incorrect in my Parent Pom.xml, causing it to spit up a slew of random errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem and for me [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447351/maven-build-android-application-buildconfig) to latest (as of march'13) v3.5.1 solved the issue.